# Need to convert Android.mk file definition to Android.bp

Tags: android, static-libraries, android-source, android-12, android.mk

I am an Android Firmware developer, working with a source of Android 12. I wanted to convert my Android.mk file to Android.bp, with the same definitions in tact in order to build a static jar library.

**Android.mk file:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# the library
# ============================================================
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src/com/example/foo/player)

# This is the target being built.
LOCAL_MODULE := com.example.foo.player

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_JACK_ENABLED := disabled

#If Android P, set LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS true.
#LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true

include $(BUILD_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have translated the definitions from Android.mk to Android.bp.

It looks like this:

```
// Android.bp

// Define the module type
java_library_static {
    name: "com.example.foo.player",
    srcs: [
        "src/com/example/foo/player/**/*.java",
    ],
    optional: true,
    proguard_flags: "proguard.flags",
    //jack_enabled: false, //Jack is deprecated in Android P, use the default value
    //private_platform_api: true, // Uncomment this if using Android P
}
```

Let me know if any corrections or improvisations is necessary.